# Simple int to char[] conversion

Tags: c, character-encoding

I have a simple question

How to simply convert integer (getting values 0-8) to char, e.g. char[2] in C?

Thanks

Comment: Why do you need 2 `char`?  Please give an example of input and corresponding output.

Comment: I dont understand why you need .

Answer (score 31, accepted):

```
main()
{
  int i = 247593;
  char str[10];

  sprintf(str, "%d", i);
// Now str contains the integer as characters
}
```

Hope it will be helpful to you.

Comment: Always use `snprintf` or `snprintf_s` and pass the buffer size to avoid buffer overflows and potential security issues, even for the simplest cases like this one. Using `sprintf` is a security issue unless you *know* the output size beforehand.

Answer (score 4):

```
#include<stdio.h> 
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<string.h>
void main()
{
int a = 543210 ;
char arr[10] ="" ;

itoa(a,arr,10) ;   // itoa() is a function of stdlib.h file that convert integer 
                   // int to array itoa( integer, targated array, base u want to             
                   //convert like decimal have 10 

for( int i= 0 ; i < strlen(arr); i++)   //  strlen()   function in string file thar return string length
  printf("%c",arr[i]);

}
```

Comment: While `itoa` is very easy to use and supported by many compilers, it seems it's not defined in ANSI-C, as noted [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/itoa/).

Answer (score 1):

Use this. Beware of i's larger than 9, as these will require a char array with more than 2 elements to avoid a buffer overrun.

```
char c[2];
int i=1;
sprintf(c, "%d", i);
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to convert an int which is in the range 0-9 to a char, you may usually write something like this:

```
int x;
char c = '0' + x;
```

Now, if you want a character string, just add a terminating '\0' char:

```
char s[] = {'0' + x, '\0'};
```

Note that:

1. You must be sure that the int is in the 0-9 range, otherwise it will fail,
2. It works only if character codes for digits are consecutive. This is true in the vast majority of systems, that are ASCII-based, but this is not guaranteed to be true in all cases.

Comment: Actually, the C standard guarantees that the representations of `'0'` to `'9'` are consecutive and ascending.

Answer (score 0):

You can't truly do it in "standard" C, because the size of an int and of a char aren't fixed. Let's say you are using a compiler under Windows or Linux on an intel PC...

> ```
> int i = 5;
> char a = ((char*)&i)[0];
> char b = ((char*)&i)[1];
> ```
>
> Remember of endianness of your machine! And that int are "normally" 32 bits, so 4 chars!

But you probably meant "i want to stringify a number", so ignore this response :-)

Answer (score 0):

char[] s = {'\0', '\0' ,'\0','\u001A'}; //s[3]=26
Int32 Data = BitConverter.ToInt32(s);//now Data=26

char[] H = new char[4];
H[3] = (char)Data; //now H == s

Comment: The question asked for C code. 12 years ago.